# Loopback throws accessToken undefined even though a user is logged in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, loopbackjs

I´m working on a loopback JS app with the angular JS SDK on frontend. I have an after hook on a the find remote method for a model which verifies if there is an access token on the current context.

```
  Team.afterRemote('find',function(context,boards,next){
      var ExeboardUser = app.models.ExeboardUser;
      var ExeboardUserBoard = app.models.ExeboardUserBoard;


      var ctx = loopback.getCurrentContext();

      var at = ctx.get('accessToken');
      if(at==undefined || at==null){
        // return 401
        console.log("Unauthorized: Find Boards-User not logged in.");
        var newError = new Error("Unauthorized: Find Boards");
        newError.status = 401;
        next(newError);
      }
      else{
        //.. more verifications and operations on the data
      }

  });
```

This verification works well.... Sometimes. The problem I´m having is that at random times I get a 401 Unauthorized because loopback got an undefined access token. This happens even though I´m logged in, and if I send again the request the token magically reappears and the permissions are granted.

I don´t know exaclty how to replicate every time this error. I just know it happens (sometimes) if I leave the session iddle for 5-10 minutes, or if I´m making changes to the frontend and I do a refresh.

On angularJS I call the endpoint at the beggining of my controller. This means that I  make the request as soon as the user enters the url which has the controller.

```
var getTeam = function(){
  Team.find({filter:{where:{ id:$stateParams.id }}})
    .$promise
    .then(function(response){
        $log.log("SUCCESS",response);

      },
      function(err){
        $log.log(err);
      });
};
```

What I can´t understand is why it happens sometimes and sometimes doesn´t. Can anyone help me spot the error?

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but in `if(at==undefined || at==null){` you only need to check for undefined *or* null, not both, because of the loose equality algorithm.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the correction on the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a remote hook, you should use the following ACL on your model:

```
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
  "permission": "DENY",
  "property": "find"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still need the token on the hook to get the currentUserId and make additional checks

Comment: fair enough, I would still recommend using loopback.token() middleware instead of having it in a remote hook, but I guess if you only need to check on the one function that works. If you can narrow down the source of the issue, can you post on the LoopBack repo on GitHub? Mention me in a comment (@richardpringle) and I'll make sure someone looks into it further.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the following?

1. Order of token and context middleware in `server.js` file. I have this order:

   ```
   app.use(loopback.context());
   app.use(loopback.token());
   ```
2. Check in console to know the location of stored access token, `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. `sessionStorage` gets removed when you close the browser tab.

I cannot use comment feature yet as my reputation is not yet 50 :). Apologies, if this looked more like comments.